# Possible problems concerning the update of token standards such as ERC20 token

Tags: upgrading, contract-upgrading

I am new to crypto. I want to ask if in the future, ERC20 Tokens become outdated, will there be a recycle  (or some kinds of buyback or repurchase ?) of old tokens or an automatic update (perhaps done alongside with wallet software update, just guessing)? What if I hold a particular cryptocurrency long enough , say the crypto use ERC 20 tokens standard, will the market price of the cryptocurrency using old token standard drop to zero since the technology become outdated?

I know many crypto projects use ERC 20 TOKEN Standard,such as BNB , LINK. So how exactly do these crypto projects keep up with the updated standards or protocol while maintaining the market price and  how ethereum community and developers deal with these problems.
Any help to enlighten me is appreciated! thank you so much.

My later thought: 
Is it right that what matters is the private key and "the public ledger". We don't have to worry about any software or hardware update?Is my thought correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not uncommon for a project to switch their token. But then it's typically from one ERC20 token to another ERC20 with a slightly different functionality.

I don't think the standard itself will become outdated anytime soon. Sure, better standards are always coming along, but it's difficult for new things to replace the ERC20 standard, since it's so widely spread already.

If, in 10 years, most tokens are using some other token standard, you would still have your ERC20 tokens. True, their value may have gone down (or up). But mostly projects do not need to worry about new standards, since there is no challenger for ERC20 in sight.

You don't need to do anything for your wallet or stuff like that - if you own a token, you own it and that's it. You won't stop owning it just because your wallet may be outdated.

The price of tokens is simply based on supply and demand. So it's impossible to say what the price of some token is in the future. If you hold a specific ERC20 and forget about it and the project around it has issued a token swap, you may be left with a useless ERC20 if you don't swap it in time.

Comment: So was there any history of token swap for update in the past?

Comment: Does owning a token meaning owning the ledger record , its private key and the software code accompanying the token standard?Is there any difference between token and coin and cryptocurrency?

Comment: Owning a token means that your address is marked as an owner for X amount of tokens, in the token contract. That's all. Please post a new question for your other questions - or better, search for existing answers

Comment: So if ERC 20 token really get update in future, what happens to ether?

Comment: I mean what will happen to my ether or ethereum in my self-custodial wallet? Do I need to do anything?